# Insert at most one leading and trailing newline after each word

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

I have strings that contain delimiters. The delimiters need to contain leading and trailing newlines but they do not. Three examples:

```
[heading 1]content[heading 2]content[heading 3]content

[heading 1]content↵
[heading 2]content↵
[heading 3]content

[heading 1]↵
content[heading 2]↵
content[heading 3]↵
content
```

I need to normalize the data using regular expression find-replace. Each delimiter must have leading and trailing newline, the first delimiter must have trailing newline only:

```
[heading 1]↵
content↵
[heading 2]↵
content↵
[heading 3]↵
content
```

I have tried this find-replace pattern ([regexr](http://www.regexr.com/3bhro)) but it does not work in all cases:

```
find: \[.+?\](?!\r\n)
repl: $0\r\n
```

**Update**: I prefer a one-regex-only solution that does not require pre and post-processing such as replace and trim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

First just replace all new lines with [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and then you can easily add a new line after each `[heading]` and the `content` with [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), e.g.

```
<?php

    $str = "[heading 1]content[heading 2]content[heading 3]content";
    $str = trim(preg_replace("/(\[.+?\])((?:[^\[])+)/", "$1" . PHP_EOL . "$2" . PHP_EOL, str_replace(PHP_EOL, "", $str)));

    highlight_string($str);

?>
```

output:

```
[heading 1]
content
[heading 2]
content
[heading 3]
content
```

**EDIT:**

If you only want to use a regex, you could do something like this:

```
<?php

    $str = "[heading 1]content[heading 2]content[heading 3]content

[heading 1]content
[heading 2]content
[heading 3]content

[heading 1]
content[heading 2]
content[heading 3]
content";

    $str = preg_replace("/\s*(\[.+?\]|(?![^\[]+$(*PRUNE))[^\[]+)\s*/", "$1" . PHP_EOL, $str);
    var_dump($str);

?>
```

Comment: [Corrected] OK you have one regex, but it is adding _two_ newlines for test case 2. @cars10 pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

The regexp

```
\s*(\[[^[\]]+])\s*
```

search for separators `\s*` before and after a heading `\[[^[\]]+]` and remove them. Output the captured heading preceded and followed by a newline character as `"\n\1\n"`.

can be used in

```
$input="[heading 1]content[heading 2]content[heading 3]content

[heading 1]content
[heading 2]content
[heading 3]content

[heading 1]
content[heading 2]
content[heading 3]
content";
$str=substr(preg_replace('\s*(\[[^[\]]+])\s*',"\n\1\n",$input),1);
```

To produce the following:

```
[heading 1]
content
[heading 2]
content
[heading 3]
content
[heading 1]
content
[heading 2]
content
[heading 3]
content
[heading 1]
content
[heading 2]
content
[heading 3]
content
```

Comment: Use `trim`, not `substr`.

Comment: Also you need to care about quotes you need `"\n"` and not `'\n'`

Comment: There is also no `g` modifier.

Comment: @Rizier and Uchiha thanks for the corrections - it is far too hot in my office at the moment ;-)

Comment: Any possibility to ditch the `substr` function?

Comment: Well, as stribizhev already mentioned, you can use `trim()` instead, but basically the regexp will put a newline before each `[` and so the first newline will always be there and needs to be removed again.

Comment: @SalmanA You ask for a *one-regex only* answer, but now you accept this answer, I'm confused.